# Magento 2 - Get product details in list view adding custom block using plugin

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento2.1, magento2.2

I was trying to use plugin system to modify block of every product listed.

I was able to set it up in this way:

**Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct">
    <plugin name="vendor.module.category.products.list" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Product\AbstractProduct" />
</type>
```

**Vendor/Module/Plugin/Block/Product/AbstractProduct.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Product;

class AbstractProduct
{
    public function afterGetProductDetailsHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct $subject,
        $result
    ) {
         // Here is where I want to pull product details like SKU
         // I also want to pull my custom helper method here
         return '<b>rendered additional html element</b>';
    }
}
```

The problem is I am not able to pull product details in `afterGetProductDetailsHtml`.
Does anybody know how to do that? Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you try arround plugin? because in that plugin you get prouct detail.

Comment: I thought they are all created equal... let me try that, thank you!

Comment: Ok try and let me know.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya that worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: I post answer, please accept it, So it will help other in community as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to used arround plugin instade of after plugin like this,

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Product;

class AbstractProduct
{
    public function aroundGetProductDetailsHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct $subject,
        callable $proceed)
    ) {
         // Here is where I want to pull product details like SKU
         // I also want to pull my custom helper method here
         return '<b>rendered additional html element</b>';
    }
}
```